# How to recursively copy files as hard links into directory preserving directory hierarchy?

Tags: shell

I'm trying to hard link files in one directory hierarchy to another directory. Code looks like this:

```
# Directories first, works fine, takes sub-second
find src_dir/sub1 src_dir/sub2 -type d -exec bash -c 'cd "$0" && mkdir -p "$@"' dest_dir {} +
# Files next, works fine, takes several seconds
find src_dir/sub1 src_dir/sub2 -type f -exec ln -f {} dest_dir/{} \;
```

The hard linking is very slow because of sequential calls to `ln`. I can't think of a form that works though, and can't find much about copy-as-hardlinks in `cp` and `rsync` manpages. Leaning towards writing a C program for the specific problem...

Before jumping down that rabbit hole, are there any suggestions how to make it faster using UNIX or otherwise renowned 3rd party tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GNU `cp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cp-invocation.html) supports hard-linking instead of copying files:

```
cp -lR src_dir dest_dir
```

If `dest_dir` already exists, this will copy `src_dir` into `dest_dir`, you’ll end up with `dest_dir/src_dir` and copies of all the directories in `src_dir`.

If you only want a subset of `src_dir`, you can copy sub-directories explicitly:

```
mkdir -p dest_dir/src_dir
cp -lR src_dir/sub1 dest_dir/src_dir/sub1
cp -lR src_dir/sub2 dest_dir/src_dir/sub2
```

Comment: My src_dir is really many directories with explicit sub-directories that I want to preserve. Will update question since it would matter in this case.

Comment: @Andreas the `-R` in option in this answer actually means "copy directories recursively", so that should already do the job ...

Comment: @AdminBee Problem is `cp -R src_dir/sub1 dest_dir` would copy sub1 directory directly into dest_dir. I want the result to be dest_dir/src_dir/sub1.

Comment: I understand that, but I think that if you actually call `cp -R src_dir dest_dir` then the entire `src_dir` _including its sub-directories_ should be copied into `dest_dir`. Perhaps you can give it a try ...

Comment: @AdminBee The reason to point out sub1 and sub2 is because I don't want to copy sub3. Then again that's because of a performance issue which cp -R might just overcome... Good talk.

Comment: This will copy `src_dir` into `dest_dir`, you’ll end up with `dest_dir/src_dir`.

Comment: Ok, If you want to exclude part of the sub-directory structure that is a different issue, of course. If the performance issue turns out to persist, you may have to use a hybrid approach using `find` to identify the "wanted" sub-directories, and `cp -R` for copying them "one by one".

Comment: Ending up with subset strategy, splitting into multiple invocations using a few Make rules and recipes.